# Passing string argument to #within_window is deprecated

Tags: capybara

I am trying to update my code because I am currently getting the following deprecation warning when running it:

"DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing string argument to #within_window is deprecated. Pass window object or lambda."

Here is the code:

```
new_window=page.driver.browser.window_handles.last 
    page.within_window new_window do
        expect(current_url).to eq("url")
    end
page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(page.driver.browser.window_handles.last)
```

How should I edit the above so I no longer get the deprecation warning? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The `within_window` method was changed to expect a Capybara::Window or a proc/lamda. Locating the window by a string, which is what `window_handles.last` returns, is what was deprecated.

To get the last Capybara::Window, use the [`windows` method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#windows-instance_method). It works similar to what was done with `window_handles`:

```
new_window = windows.last
page.within_window new_window do
    expect(current_url).to eq("url")
end
```

Note that the documentation states that "The order of windows in returned array is not defined. The driver may sort windows by their creation time but it's not required.". I think the same was true when using `window_handles` so it is probably safe to assume that the last window is the new window.

However, where possible, it would probably be better to locate the window by something specific such as the title:

```
within_window(->{ page.title == 'New window title' }) do
  expect(current_url).to eq("url")
end
```